# npm run watch for angular 17 which port it will run the app?

Tags: angular17

I have created new angular project with version 17(without server side rendering and using static render only). Have not added any code yet, it is the same folder and file structure which is generated using `ng new` command.

I ran the command `npm run watch` command, it watches the build but not able to find which localhost port it is exposing.

If anyone has encountered this build watch finding port issue in the past then please help me in this.

Thanks

Comment: That command doesn't start a dev server

Answer (score -1):

The npm run watch command is typically used to run the Angular development server with automatic rebuilding and reloading capabilities. However, the command itself doesn't explicitly specify a port, and Angular CLI usually defaults to port 4200 for the development server.

If you're not seeing any information about the port when you run npm run watch, you can check the angular.json file in the root of your Angular project. Look for the "serve" options under the "architect" section. It might look something like this:

```
"options": {
"port": 4200,
// other options...
}
```

Make sure the "port" property is set to 4200. If it's not there, Angular CLI should still default to port 4200.

If you want to specify a different port, you can add the --port option to your npm run watch command. For example:

```
npm run watch -- --port=3000
```